# Opening up a CMYK PSD file in GImp (2.8)

Tags: gimp, photoshop, cmyk

I am running [Gimp 2.8](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp) and tried to open up a CMYK psd file and got this error:

`Opening 'homepage.psd' failed: Procedure 'file-psd-load' returned no return values`

Am I missing a plugin? Is there a way to do this? My preference is not to use tools like imagemagick to convert the psd into many pngs but rather to open it directly in Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

GIMP won't open CMYK PSD files, it simply doesn't have CMYK mode for images. It will convert and open CMYK TIFF files, however, via separate+ plug-in.